# How can I change font from system to custom in UI slider. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, uilabel

How can I change font from system to custom in `UISlider` element. I want to change system font to - Custom font (Bodoni 72 Book), How can I do that?

My code -

```
@IBAction func UISlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    print("Slider value \(UISlider.value)")

    myLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(UISlider.value * 72.0))

}
```

Problem - When using the slider, it changes the custom font back to system font.

Comment: What is self.UILable ???

Comment: UILable is the text field where i want to change the font.

Comment: oh that's your actual variable name?  Don't do that, it's awfully confusing.  Name it something clearer like `var sliderLabel: UILabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code, you are assigning `UIFont.systemFont(...` to the `font` property of the label.

I changed UILable to sliderLabel

You need:

```
self.sliderLabel.font = UIFont(name: someFontFamilyName, size: CGFloat(UISlider.value * 72.0))
```

Comment: Yes.! But iam having trouble adding font name..! As This is the font name = Bodoni72.

Comment: self.UILable.font = UIFont(name: Bodoni72Book, size: CGFloat(UISlider.value * 72.0))

Comment: Its a Custom font , Family = Bodoni72 and style = Book

Comment: I don't know what the family name for Bonodi72 is.  There are many resources available to find this.  When you find the exact name you have to put it in quotes because `name` requires a string!  i.e., "Bonodi72Book"